# Image matrices defined in Susy aren't lining up properly

Tags: susy-compass

I think I managed to solve most of my starting problems with Susy. The only odd thing left I can't figure out is why it behaves the way it does when creating an image matrix.

Here's my setup:

```
$total-columns: 24;
$column-width: 6%;
$gutter-width: 1%;
$grid-padding: 0;

$container-style: magic;
```

Here's the HTML code:

```
    <section name="Projekte" class="projects" role="main">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="maintitle">Unsere Projekte</h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <ul class="moodlegrid">
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte1" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte2" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte3" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte4" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte5" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte6" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte7" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte8" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>
            <li><a href=""></a><img title="Projekte9" src="img/projekte.jpg"  /></li>           
        </ul>
        <div class="proper"></div>
    </section><!-- end section -->
```

This should be a 3x3 matrix of images and elsewhere on the page there should be a 7x4 matrix of images, but both act odd. Both don't respect that there are 3 margin columns at both sides as well as their position.

The supposed 7x4 matrix looks like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8578/7x4.png), and
the supposed 3x3 matrix looks like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8578/3x3.png).

Here's the CSS code:

```
section {
    @include boxcolor($section-container);
    width: 100%;
    @include no-bullets;
    @include box-shadow(black 2px 2px 10px);
    margin-bottom: 2*1.5em;
    padding-bottom: 2*1.5em;
    clear: both;
}

.customers li {
    @include squish(3,3);
    @include span-columns(2,18);
    @include nth-omega(7n);
    margin-left:0;
}

.moodlegrid li{
    @include squish(3,3);
    @include span-columns(6,18);
    @include nth-omega(3n);
    margin-left:0;
}
```

That's it for the moment. Has anybody a slightest idea why Susy is behaving like this? Especially on the 3x3 matrix, where everything should basically fit in: `6 + 3*6` equals to the number of columns I have set. Confusing somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to squish the same elements that you are using for you columns. You want to squish the parent. Currently, `squish` is not doing anything, because you override it with `span-columns`.

```
.customers {
  @include squish(3,3);
  li {
    @include span-columns(2,18);
    @include nth-omega(7n);
  }
}

.moodlegrid 
  @include squish(3,3);
  li{
    @include span-columns(6,18);
    @include nth-omega(3n);
  }
}
```